# Unwrapping a java manifest file fin bash

Tags: bash, manifest.mf

In Java, META-INF/MANIFEST.MF files have a maximum line length. Beyond that, an automatic line break is inserted, signaled by a space at the beginning of the next line, like so:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: com.google.common.net;uses:="com.google.common.base,ja
 vax.annotation[file continues]
Bundle-Name: Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java
```

Unfortunately, this makes it painful to `grep` and `sed` in bash.

How would you go about unwrapping it, using bash, into this?

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: com.google.common.net;uses:="com.google.common.base,javax.annotation[file continues]
Bundle-Name: Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java
```

I'd try `sed`, but it works only on a per line basis, and I can't get `tr` to work properly either.

Thanks!

EDIT: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318189/sed-with-newlines-and)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -0777 -wpe 's/\n //g' MANIFEST.MF
```

It removes every instance of a line-break followed by a space.

Comment: Awesome! This does the trick, thanks! Just one detail due to windows generated files, you need to also remove the \r, using: `perl -0777 -wpe 's/\r?\n //g' MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: Worked for me, too, but my MANIFEST.MF contains carriage-return characters, so the lines were overwritten. `perl ... | tr -d '\r'` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use -z to separate by lines with null, -i to edit in-place

```
sed -i -z 's:\n ::g' MANIFEST.MF
```

My manifests have CRs so

```
sed -i -z -r 's:\r?\n ::g' MANIFEST.MF
```